# how to get the value returned from the function and use it another function

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to make a function for sanitize the fields using regex in javascript. This is my function. My end goal is to get a string and sanitize it and reuse it somewhere. like I this scenario I need the string

```
function sani(str){
    str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
    return str;
}

$('button').click(function(){
    var word = "<h1>Hello W<o>rld";
    alert(str);
    cleanStr(str);
    //I need the following alert to be the string after sanitisation
    alert("After sanitisation : "+str)
})
```

Comment: Your function is called `sani` but you're calling `cleanStr`. You're using `str` variable when your variable is called `word`. Change it to: `var word = "<h1>Hello W<o>rld"; word = sani(word); alert("After sanitisation : " + word)`

Comment: call the function inside another function using `sani("some string")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to call `sani` and not `cleanStr` you can do the following:

```
function sani(str){
    str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
    return str;
}

$('button').click(function(){
    var word = "<h1>Hello W<o>rld";
    alert(word);
    var result = sani(word);
    //I need the following alert to be the string after sanitisation
    alert("After sanitisation : " + result)
})
```